# UTF-8 encoding in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have a MySQL database, set to use UTF-8.

In my database.yml, the database is set to utf8.

I am doing some HTML scraping and inserting into the MySQL database.

If I retrieve the HTML from the database in PHP, it correctly encodes all characters and produces fine input:

```
// code
$result = mysql_query("SELECT raw_html FROM pages WHERE id = 1");
echo mysql_result($result,0);

// output
Hawaiʻi.
```

And the output looks great. However, in rails, I get strange characters:

```
// code in the controller
@page = Page.find(params[:id])

// code in the view
<%= @page.raw_html %>

// output
HawaiÊ»i
```

Is there somewhere else I need to force UTF-8? I've tried using the iconv library to no avail (unless I'm using it wrong).

UPDATE: 
I've reproduced the same problem when using the console. So:

```
Page.find(2).raw_html[91..94]

"Ê»"
```

The problem also occurs under the console (script/console) if that sheds any more light on the issue.

UPDATE 2:
Okay, on further investigation I've realized I was doing something dumb. But it didn't fix it.

While the table was set to UTF8, the column was not. I've changed the column to be 'utf8_general_ci'. However (and this makes me think I'm screwing something basic up), this actually produces the correct result:

```
@raw_html = Iconv.conv('LATIN1','UTF-8',@page.raw_html[0..10000])
```

That comes out lovely. Unfortunately, if I run the whole page through, I get:

```
Iconv::IllegalSequence in PagesController#show 
"€²18â€³N<"...
```

So there's some other funky stuff going on in there. Could it be that I still have it 'latin' encoded, even though I've explicitly set both the table and the column to UTF-8 (and repopulated the HTML) ? I'm currently using the mysql2 gem as well, per Jeffrey's suggestion.

UPDATE 3: To clarify, I'm getting console errors as well. This is the command:

```
Page.find(2).raw_html[91..94]
```

And this is the response:

```
"Ê»"
```

Comment: Ignore the controller for a minute, and narrow this down a bit. What is the output in the console?

Comment: I'm only selecting the relevant characters with this statement: Page.find(2).raw_html[91..94]
"Ê»"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your database.yml add `encoding: utf8` to each of your environment setups.

Comment: In which case the problem maybe that you do not need it, you need to add this when the collation of your database is set to utf8 but if yours is set to latin or similar then you will not need this. Removing may very well fix your problem.

Comment: WOW Thank you this worked! I deleted the collation and now the text is outputting correctly. Why, though? I don't understand; if the database is UTF-8 (and at this point I've checked repeatedly), why would removing this magically make it work?

Comment: This is because of the collation setting of the database, tables and fields, older versions of mysql did not have this so at a connection level nothing needed to communicated to the db about encoding. Later when mysql implemented collations its default collation was latin. In order to use a utf collation you needed to use the mysql command "SET NAMES 'utf8'" this is what the encoding: utf8 in your database.yml file does. Take it out and it goes back to the default. MySql often causes garbled characters because of this. Weirdly you can store utf8 in a non-utf8 collated database & vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You might to switch to mysql2 :)

Set it both your gem file and database.yml

adapter: mysql2

gem "mysql2"

That should save you a lot of trouble :)

Comment: Tried, this, but it didn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have set the character encoding for the html page in your layout

If you are using HTML5, try adding this as the first line in your page

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

For HTML 4, try adding this to the head section of the page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

For XHTML pages, try

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

if you are serving with the text/html MIME type, and this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

as the very first line of the served file if its XHTML served as XML

Comment: It's XHTML, and it's set to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> but no dice